# Open Windows Explorer with Microsoft Edge, without "Did you mean to switch apps?" message

Tags: html, windows-10, microsoft-edge, windows-explorer

I have an in-house web application that opens Windows Explorer folders using something like this:

```
<a href="file://SOME-NETWORK-SHARE" target="_blank">Click here to open folder</a>
```

This works fine in Internet Explorer on Windows 7. 
Note: the site is included in Trusted Sites, with additional security changes.

I have now upgraded several of our PCs to Windows 10 and although the site still works fine in Internet Explorer (without any prompts), in Microsoft Edge, the user is prompted to confirm:

> "Did you mean to switch apps?"

Upon confirming the message, Windows Explorer opens.
But is there any way to disable this message?

I have searched around but nothing matches my problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered on [Microsoft Tech website](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/175ddf01-f91b-4eb3-b9bd-e9ac243e8de6/microsoft-edge-accessing-windows-explorer-did-you-mean-to-switch-apps-can-this-be-removed?forum=win10itprogeneral):

REGEDIT

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\ProtocolExecute\
```

Add a key named `file` and add a `dword key` `WarnOnOpen` with value `0`.